# Odd characters in JSON data, replaced with a "takeout character"?

Tags: postman

I'm using TVHeadend as a TV-to-network server. It has a JSON API for things like channel lists and electronic program guide (EPG). My problem is that the EPG data sometimes contains accented characters, which causes the iOS client to choke.

To debug, I used Postman on macOS to examine the data I was getting from the server. Here is an example of one of the EPG entries with "bad" data as viewed in Postman:

```
{
  "eventId": 14277,
  "episodeId": 14278,
  "channelName": "49.3 CometTV",
  "channelUuid": "02fe96403d58d53d71fde60649bf2b9a",
  "channelNumber": "49.3",
  "start": 1480266000,
  "stop": 1480273200,
  "title": "The Brain That Wouldn't Die",
  "description": "Dr. Bill Cortner and his fianc�e, Jan Compton , are driving to his lab when they get into a horrible car accident. Compton is decapitated. But Cortner is not fazed by this seemingly insurmountable hurdle. His expertise is in transplants, and he is excited to perform the first head transplant. Keeping Compton's head alive in his lab, Cortner plans the groundbreaking yet unorthodox surgery. First, however, he needs a body."
},
```

As you can see, Postman has "translated" the accented character in a takeout. This is fine, so does anyone know the logic they use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably in the TVHeadend configuration and related to the channel's compliance with the required character set.  I don't think you can fix it on the receiving end.

You may want to look at this thread for more info:

https://tvheadend.org/issues/1775

Comment: So the problem with this is that TVH stores old EPG data. So when you change the configuration you may or may not change the data you receive. This is very confusing, because you may see no result of your changes. In the end I wrote code on the client side to filter out all of this.